# How can I remove the character ' when writing with XLConnect?

Tags: r, dataframe, xlconnect

I want to export a data frame to a xls file. I found the library XLConnect, which is easy to use, but I would not mind trying something else.

The problem I have is in the output (xls file). Since my data frame contains strings like 'A_B', the output contains the character ' before each integer. This is a problem for me because I need OpenOffice to detect column with integers to be able to apply formulas later on.

Here is a small example without any problems, meaning each entry in the xls file is an integer.

```
library(XLConnect)
test = as.data.frame(matrix(c(0,0),nrow=1),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
wb =loadWorkbook('file.xls',create=TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "test")
writeWorksheet(wb,test,'test',header=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

The problem occurs in the following example.

```
library(XLConnect)
test = as.data.frame(matrix(c(0,'A_B'),nrow=1),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
wb =loadWorkbook('file.xls',create=TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "test")
writeWorksheet(wb,test,'test',header=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

In this last example, the first entry in the xls file is '0, which is not detected as an integer in OpenOffice.

Is there a way to remove the character ' from the output data ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XLConnect, the column types of a `data.frame` determine the resulting cell types. E.g. `character` columns result in string/text cells while `numeric` columns result in numeric cells.

In your example, the expression `c(0, 'A_B')` results in a `character` vector (R automatically coerces your `0` to `character`) and as such the resulting cells written will be string/text cells (see `str(test)` to investigate your `data.frame`). As such, you should be fine by simply constructing your `data.frame` differently, e.g. by doing the following:

`test = data.frame(NumericColumn = 0, TextColumn = "A_B", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(test)`

Looking at the output of `str(test)` you should now see that "NumericColumn" is a `numeric` column and "TextColumn" is a `character` column. When writing that `data.frame` with XLConnect, you will see that the resulting cells will have the appropriate cell type.

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Thank you very much! The reason why I built my data frame that way is because I collect my data by line, so I wanted to use rbind to add a line at a time. I can always collect data in columns and add the columns to the data frame at end, but this require more memory.